# Windows 10 Powershell Automation Script Issue

Tags: powershell, automation, amp-html, windows-10-desktop

I am currently stuck on a pretty significant issue, so much so that it seems even Google does not have an answer for it. Here is my situation. I have a program that takes an html file as input and converts the tags into AMP-valid format. For some reason, after conversion, it bunches up all the code onto a single line, so I have to go in, scroll to each tag, and press [enter] in order to move the tag onto a new line. My question is this, how the heck do I write a mini-script that can run after the conversion to do this one simple function? For the life of me, I can not figure it out. Someone please help!

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you for those links, they were very helpful!